# Accessing remotely my web service

Tags: ios, iphone, url, localhost, restful-url

I have implemented a web service on my mac and I am able to access its functionalities through the url "http://localhost:8080/ServiceApp-war/resources/". 
As I got satisfying results that I could see in the iPhone simulator in Xcode, I decided to connect my iPhone and test on it. But for this to work I think I need to change the "localhost" in my URL to the IP address of my mac.

I tried to replace it with my public IP address and I got a "could not connect to the server" error on my console. I also tried to replace "localhost" with the IP address I found in System Preferences-->Network-->Wi-Fi and I could see that it was working on the simulator but still nothing when I connect my iPhone and run the application on it.

Please provide a solution for accessing my web service remotely.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ngrok was the perfect solution I was looking for.
https://ngrok.com

Answer (score 0):

Create hotspot from your mac, connect to it with your iPhone and try again.

```
<lame solution>
Try some service for temporary domain, it will make your computer accessible from anywhere.
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you "connect" your iPhone? USB connection does **not** create a network. Well, it does create if you turn on Personal Hotspot on your iPhone (maybe in some other cases, dunno). But the most simple way is to connect Mac and iPhone to the same WiFi network.

Once connected, you can use any of "ping" apps available on App Store. Just look for "ping" (some kind of "network reachability test" or so). You can check if your Mac is really reachable on the network.

If it's not reachable, check your network settings on both devices: do they belong to the same subnet, do they use the same gateway, etc.

If your Mac is reachable with ping, then you should deal with your web service. I setup the web server (which is already distributed within OS X): it already has all the settings to allow other devices to connect. But your web service may require some additional setup. It's two basic things: it should bind to your IP address (please check http://YOUR.IP:8080/ServiceApp-war/resources/ from your Mac!) and second, accept incoming connections from other agents, you should find it somewhere in its settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try finch, which is similar to ngrok. It has a nice friendly GUI. https://meetfinch.com